# how to pass multiple values in single parameter and how to convert varchar value into integers

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

```
CREATE TABLE students
( id INT,
  NAME  varchar(20)
)

INSERT INTO students(id,name)VALUES(1,'Danny')
INSERT INTO students(id,name)VALUES(2,'Dave')
INSERT INTO students(id,name)VALUES(3,'Sue')
INSERT INTO students(id,name)VALUES(4,'Jack')
INSERT INTO students(id,name)VALUES(5,'Rita')
INSERT INTO students(id,name)VALUES(6,'Sarah')
```

This is my stored procedure

```
alter PROCEDURE emp_sp 
(
@std_id as VARCHAR(500),
@std_name as varchar(500)
)
AS
begin 
SELECT *FROM Students s
WHERE s.id IN(convert(INT,@std_id) ,',')
AND 
s.NAME IN(@std_name)
END
GO
```

Here I execute it manually

```
EXEC dbo.emp_sp @std_id='1,2,3', @std_name='"Danny","Dave","Sue"'
```

but I get this error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Procedure emp_sp, Line 8
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ',' to data type int.

Anyone can guide me.

Comment: Well, the `IN()` operator expects a **list of items** (in your case: a list of strings) - but what you're supplying to it is **a single string**. What you need to do is **split up** that comma-separated string into a list of strings and then use that in your `IN` - or better yet: use a **table-valued parameter** to pass in a proper list of multiple values to your stored procedure in the first place!

Answer (score 0):

To get your current approach working, you will need to use Dynamic Sql, which will be incredibly fragile and prone to Sql Injection attacks. [Example of this Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ebd5e/3)

The better way to do this is through Table Valued Parameters:

```
CREATE TYPE ttStudentIDs AS TABLE
(
  ID INT
);
GO

CREATE TYPE ttStudentNames AS TABLE
(
  Name VARCHAR(20)
);
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.emp_sp 
(
   @stdIds ttStudentIDs READONLY,
   @stdNames ttStudentNames READONLY
)
AS
begin

   SELECT s.ID, s.Name
   FROM Students s
   INNER JOIN @stdIds si 
   ON s.ID = si.ID

   UNION

   SELECT s.ID, s.Name
   FROM Students s
   INNER JOIN @stdNames  sn
   ON s.Name = sn.Name;
END
GO
```

And called like so:

```
DECLARE @Ids AS ttStudentIDs;
DECLARE @Names AS ttStudentNames;

INSERT INTO @Ids VALUES (1),(2),(3);
INSERT INTO @Names VALUES ('Danny'),('Dave'),('Sue');

EXEC dbo.emp_sp @Ids, @Names;
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/95286/3)